# Submitting an app to the App Store with a predefined release date and later posting an update

Tags: ios, app-store, updates, appstore-approval

We are submitting an app to the App Store this week with a predefined release date (lets say its the 15. of December 2012).

Lets presume, that the app is approved.
If we (after the approval) post an update (hypothetically on the 10th of December), would the app still launch on the 15. of December (without the update) or will the whole release date be pushed back until the update is approved?

Any info will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The app will launch with whichever version is currently approved for sale by Apple. If the approval has happened of your new version, then it will be released. Otherwise, the older version will.

It is worth noting that Apple does not review apps for a period of time over the holiday period.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Just got that email! The shut down is from December 21st to the 28th if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

your app will go live on the date you want it to release. so it means if you set your app's launch date to 15th, and that you upload another version it will be launched on 15th
but keep in mind that, you can't upload a new version until your app is arrived